# Create new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> type using IDictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary

Hi I have a list of users. Each User belongs to an Area.

What I'm wanting to do with this list is create a dictionary from them where the Area Name is the Key and the value for the key is a selectList of Users in the Area the with a Text value of the Username and a Value set to the User Id.

I managed to achieve this using the following code:

```
    var StaffByArea = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>>();

    foreach(var area in areas)) {
                        var personList = new List<SelectListItem>();
                        foreach (var person in staff.Where(c => c.AreaId == area.Id)) {
                            personList.Add(new SelectLis

tItem { Value = person.AreaId.ToString(), Text = person.Username });
                    }

                    StaffByArea.Add(area.Name, personList);
            }
```

So for every possible area I'm finding correlating staff and adding them to a selectlist. Once I've added all the people for the area I add that select list to the dictionary with the area name as key.

I've been thinking this maybe easier to do with ToDictionary()

Does anyone know how to do this?

I've only got as far as:

StaffByArea = Users.ToDictionary(x => x.Area.Name, ...);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var StaffByArea
    = areas.ToDictionary(
        a => a.Name,
        a => staff
                .Where(c => c.AreaId == area.Id)
                .Select(c => new SelectListItem 
                { 
                    Value = c.AreaId.ToString(), 
                    Text = c.Username 
                }));
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. Obviously I need to learn my Linq better.